# why doesn't pip install package when using tox?

Tags: python, pytest, tox

I created a package the structure of which is given here.

```
packagename
   -- packagename
         -- __init__.py
   -- setup.py
```

The package installed correctly and I checked with 'pip freeze'

I am trying to use this package in another module with tox

tox.ini

```
 [tox]
  envlist = dev
 [default-dependencies]
  deps = packagename
 [testenv:dev]
  deps = {[default-dependencies]deps}
  pip_pre=True
  ignore_errors=True
  commands = py.test blah
```

when I try to this using

```
tox -e dev
```

I get this error message

```
Collecting packagename
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement packagename (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for packagename
v = InvocationError('/Users/***/.tox/dev/bin/pip install --pre dlb_dcp_csaf')
```

However, everything is good when I install like this

```
 pip install --pre packagename
```

I checked the pip version for both

```
 pip 8.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
 pip 8.1.1 from /Users/***/.tox/dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Can anyone please help why I couldn't install the package using tox but can install using pip manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the output from tox command, it looks like you haven't specified the correct path to the packagename, and hence tox is trying to look for it on PIP servers. You have to specify the correct path to the packagename that is relative to the directory where your tox.ini is located.

From: http://testrun.org/tox/latest/config.html

```
deps=MULTI-LINE-LIST
test-specific dependencies - to be installed into the environment prior to 
project package installation. Each line defines a dependency, which will be     
passed to the installer command for processing. Each line specifies a file, 
a URL or a package name.
```

...

```
(Experimentally introduced in 1.6.1) all installer commands are executed 
using the {toxinidir} as the current working directory.

{toxinidir}
the directory where tox.ini is located
```

Answer (score 0):

tox will install the package you're testing (i.e. `./setup.py`) by itself, no need to add that to `deps`.

Comment: It does install the package that I am testing. However the package that I am testing has a dependency on another package that I created. Tox is not finding that package.